# Javascript - Send Javascript Variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, settimeout

I want to send the value of a JavaScript variable (variableToSend) to a PHP variable ($latLong) which then gets posted to MySQL.  The JavaScript variable is capturing the value of an HTML textbox outside of a form listed below:

```
<input type="text" id="latLng" value="Working"/>
```

The textbox value passes to the Javascript variable just fine (I've tested via an alert with the variable's value):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
             setTimeout(function(){
                var variableToSend = document.getElementById("latLng").value;
                $.post('html/index.php', {$latLong: "variableToSend"});
            }, 10000);
    </script>
```

However, the $.post method is not firing.  I'm thinking one of a couple of things were happening.  One, the text field was not in a form which is why it didn't pass to the PHP variable.  I tested this by throwing the text field back in a form tag, but that didn't work.  Second, the $.post method is written incorrectly.  Third, the $.post method is not firing at all after the 10 second interval.  I'm thinking it's the third case but would like some direction if at all possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you loading `jQuery`? I'm assuming not considering you aren't telling anything to load once the DOM is ready.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console (including *Network* errors for the AJAX request)? Also, the `language` attribute on `<script>` tags is redundant these days (as is the more modern but still redundant `type` attribute)

Comment: I am loading jquery.

Comment: The correct syntax is `{ latLong: variableToSend }` – maybe that's simply your issue?

Comment: @deceze well, nothing wrong with dollar-sign prefixed object property names but OP seems to think the AJAX request isn't firing at all (with the input value or a static string). Won't know anything till they look in their console though

Answer (score 0):

You can use a QueryString appended to the script. Another better option would be to use the FormData object.

Here is a sample from MDN:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to string "123456"

// HTML file input user's choice...
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

// JavaScript file-like object...
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

Comment: Did you answer the wrong question? This doesn't match the question at all

Comment: He wants to get a javascript variable into MySQL.  If they follow the above they can easily do that.  I don't believe this is inaccurate at all.

Comment: Did you comment on the wrong answer because it appears you may not have read the question clearly?

Comment: OP's main problem seems to be that the call to `$.post` within the timeout callback isn't firing.